# React Native on Android: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

EDIT: I am uncertain which steps I took to resolve this problem, and am no longer seeing this error message so I cannot test the solutions below. Please try them individually as different answers seem to be working for different people.

The iOS version works fine, but running Android Studio on my Mac I get the following Gradle Build error (paraphrased):

```
:ReactNative:Running ‘[node, -e, console.log(require(‘react-native/cli’).bin);]’ command failed.

- Where:
Script ‘/Users/…/Desktop/…/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle’ line: 154

- What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Cannot run program “node”: error=2, No such file or directory

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program “node”: error=2, No such file or directory
```

I've tried so many things:

- Following the React Native development set-up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
- Following this advice about [renaming?] the node path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54007652
- Following this advice about symlink: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52779097
- Ran brew install node. Message: node 14.2.0 is already installed, it’s just not linked. Tried to run brew link --overwrite node, error /usr/local/share/doc/node is not writable.
- Tried to uninstall and reinstall all the package managers, node, yarn, whatever.

I used to be able to still run yarn android in Terminal, but even that has stopped working.

Comment: JetBrains issue was created for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-7313

Answer (score 393):

It's because Android Studio couldn't find node and should be run from a terminal window.

If you are using Mac you can run Android Studio using this command in terminal.  Note that if Android Studio is already running, it will need to be shut down completely before running the command.

**1. Run this** `open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app`

If you installed Android Studio through Jetbrains Toolbox version 1.x, run

```
open -a ~/Applications/JetBrains\ Toolbox/Android\ Studio.app
```

If you installed Android Studio through Jetbrains Toolbox version 2.x, run

```
open "Applications/Android Studio.app"
```

**2. Then sync Gradle**

And this will solve the problem.

Note: If you are using Node through nvm, you should run `nvm use [version]` in the same terminal window before running the above command to open Android Studio.

Comment: Worked for me on Apple Silicon
@TimurGaitov for whatever reason Android Studio is not using .zshrc PATH vars so opening it from terminal ensures that it will

Comment: I guess, this is a bug in Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1. Same for me on Intel Mac. Related bug report, I found: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-7313

Comment: Fixed in Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1 (February 2022): https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2022/02/android-studio-bumblebee-202111-patch-1.html

Comment: This worked but you may better upgrade to the latest Android Studio which also solved the problem. For me it's from 2021.x.x to 2022.3.1

Comment: @PabloMiranda Doesn't work for me. Any other workaround?

Comment: Using `Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1` and it is still the same node error, so it is definitely not fixed in later Android Studio versions.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. I encountered this issue previously and it has been solved. But suddenly got this again. Damn RN!

Answer (score 105):

In my case with this setup:

- Apple chip M1
- Android Studio arctic fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2

I previously ran the command mentioned above, but I kept getting the same error:

```
sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/local/bin/node
```

I had to update the gradle version in the project (*android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties*)

from:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip
```

and execute this command in the project:

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

or just delete this folder instead of the executing the previous command: *android/.gradle*

And after doing these steps I no longer have any problem.

Comment: I am already on Gradle 6.9 and I still have this issue.

Comment: Its not working for me in M1 Macbook Pro

Answer (score 98):

Simply linking node (installed previously by nvm) to `/usr/local/bin/node`.

```
sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/local/bin/node
```

**Ubuntu 20.4, Node 14.15.0**

Comment: this doesn't resolve the issue for some reason, I'm on macOS catalina, do u have an idea what else I could try ?

Comment: This resolved my issue. The reason why this worked is because I used to run Android Studio from terminal which had the `.bashrc` loaded and thus knew where to find node executable. The problem occurred when I ran Android Studio outside the terminal and my `.bashrc` did not load. If node is installed using nvm, then it won't have an executable on the PATH, unless you explicitly add it to the PATH. The command above will add a symlink to `/usr/local/bin/` which is on the PATH and it will point to the location of node executable.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu latest. Android terminal was somehow able to run node, but build command always gave error about node.

Answer (score 55):

## Solution

Running `chmod +x /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv` in the terminal and restarting Android Studio will make the gradle sync work again.

## Detail

I am using the latest Android Studio and I did a patch update of the application. My system is running macOS 12.1 on a M1 Pro Apple CPU.

After the restart I could not run my react native application and the gradle sync failed. Any fixes above did not help for me. So I read the gradle log file `idea.log` in detail. In the very beginning in the log I see the application `printenv` has some issues.

```
loading shell env: /bin/zsh -l -i -c '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv' '/var/folders/7y/gz2kx4917yl_804mbfrnkqxc0000gn/T/intellij-shell-env.9046002349811239017.tmp' 
...
.intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - can't get shell environment 
java.io.IOException: command [/bin/zsh, -l, -i, -c, '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv' '/var/folders/7y/gz2kx4917yl_804mbfrnkqxc0000gn/T/intellij-shell-env.9046002349811239017.tmp']
exit code:126 text:0 out:zsh:1: permission denied: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv
```

After that I go to folder /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/ and list `printenv` in my terminal and saw that `printenv` did not have the execute rights:

`-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  admin  152080 Jan 28 09:12 printenv`

**Android Studio**

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8092744, built on January 19, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 10
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

Comment: This was the issue for me also, same setup. Though the command had to be entered as follows to escape the space in the directory: `chmod +x /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv`

Comment: This fixed the issue for me as well after upgrading to Android Studio Bumblebee. For anyone who installs Android Studio through Jetbrains Toolbox, the fix is the same, just with a different path, i.e. `chmod +x ~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/211.7628.21.2111.8092744/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv`

Answer (score 39):

For M1 Mac, I downloaded Android Studio (Mac with Apple Chip) version and faced this issue.

It got fixed for me by changing the gradle version to 6.9-rc-1.

This can be done from File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Gradle Version -> Type or select "6.9-rc-1" and click OK button.

You can find similar and more solutions here as well.

[Gradle sync failed: Cause: error=2, No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018879/gradle-sync-failed-cause-error-2-no-such-file-or-directory#)

Answer (score 24):

Android Studio uses PATH environment variable that is available when the Android Studio process is started up, and your Node binary directory should be in that PATH.

I got this same error in Linux when I had Node installed via n (Node version management tool) which sets the Node path at Bash startup.

The problem in my case was that I started the Android Studio from the desktop and because the Bash startup file was not executed, also the Node path was not set.

The solution was to run Android Studio from the command line.

You could also try to pass the PATH environment variable directly to Android Studio while starting it from the command line:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/node/bin/ /path/to/android/studio/bin/studio.sh
```

Comment: Since my `node` is already in `/usr/local/bin/node`, the answer from @Mostav doesn't help. However, open Android Studio from terminal as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36878843/9723036) resolves the issue. I don't have to specify the PATH.

Comment: @FanchenBao you can add the path in the file bin/studio.sh then you don't have to run android studio from command line

Answer (score 18):

I'm on my Mac, and i solve this by close the android studio completely（close the process）, and restart it.

Comment: Thanks, seems to happen after MacOS updates for some reason, but a restart fixes.

Comment: that fixed it for me. on Mac, you can press `command + q` to close an app entirely

Answer (score 17):

Had the same issue in **m1 mac** and opening the android studio via **terminal** worked for me
`open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app`

Comment: There is already an accepted answer with the same solution. It would be better to keep @Aly's answer as primary choice.

Comment: Doesn't work for my m2 Mac.

Answer (score 9):

On a Mac with M1, upgrading Android Studio fixed the issue for me.
I upgraded from Arctic Fox to Bumblebee.

Also used this version of Gradle (android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties):

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into this issue as well, and for me the solution was to stop the running Gradle daemon:

```
./gradlew --stop
```

Answer (score 6):

**How I solved the same issue.**

1. Open Android studio via terminal
2. Build Project Like before

**Note:** I installed node via nvm (I believe that's why I had the issue)

If you installed android studio via snap then its pretty simple to launch it via command line.

Open project folder in terminal and run:

`android-studio .`

Answer (score 6):

Invalidate Caches & Restart on File Tab in Android Studio.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this a long time on my M1 mac mini.
I was getting this error after opening RN android project in Intellij IDEA during gradle sync and also while trying to run ./gradlew commands from command line.

What seems to be a solution for me:

- rm -rf .gradle (in the RN_PROJECT/android folder)
- killall java (to stop running gradle daemon)
- updated node to v16.8.0

I think the real solution is the first step. Now the project opens in IDEA without errors and I can run ./gradlew commands.

Answer (score 5):

In android Studio, I solved this problem when it happened to me as follows:

1 - Go to File - Invalidate Caches / Restart;
2 - Choose the option "Invalidate and Restart".

Answer (score 3):

I have tried most of the answers posted here but the only solution worked was to upgrading the gradle to 6.9 or later.

File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Gradle Version = 6.9(Select version 6.9 or later from dropdown).

Wait for it to download all modules and it should load your project.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it work in android studio bumblebee by running this command in terminal on mac,

```
sudo chmod +x /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv
```

and then restart the android studio.

Answer (score 2):

you can use:
open your project -> run:

> npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle

Comment: run: open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app

Answer (score 2):

Adding what worked for me on MacOs Monterey.

I updated the graddle version using one of the solutions here.
This can be done from File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Gradle Version -> Type or select "6.9-rc-1" and click OK button.

Double-check if node is installed with node --version, if it is
open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
Open the project and the error should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You can kill `gradle` daemon, or just restart your machine if you made some changes, and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Many of these answers are half-right but you must do both of these things:

1. Make sure that the $PATH variable includes wherever your `node` is installed. You will will probably set this in `.bashrc`.
2. Start Android Studio from the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

Change the default JDK version from Android studio embeded JDK11 to JDK zulu version. That works for me on Apple M2.
This changed the gradle scripts running env PATH, after which node can be found. But I don't know why this change affect env.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on M1 mac, found a solution after 3 days, it was because of nvm and `.zsh` having issues. If you used `brew` to install it like i did, it's going to cause a lot of issues.

### Solution:

I had to [uninstall nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/298)

```
rm -rf ~/.nvm
rm -rf ~/.npm
rm -rf ~/.bower
```

Then install nvm via instructions on [readme on its github page](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating)

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
```

Other than that, there is a section about [troubleshooting M1 macs](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#macos-troubleshooting), that might help futher if needed. But other than that, Android Studio works fine now without having to open it via terminal or any other work-arounds. (You might have to agree to the sdk license agreement if your build fails, view the build tab for the issue, to agree to the license, just go to Tools > Sdk Manager and uninstall the sdk, click apply and retick it and Apply to reinstall it and it will ask you about the license agreement also.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a specific answer to the question, but as some of the comments here helped me resolve my issue, maybe this answer will help someone else.

I was struggling to run a Gradle project using Intellij IDEA on Ubuntu 22.04. It was giving me the same error: `Cannot run program "X": error=2, No such file or directory`.

Here is what I did to overcome that:

`echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/X' >> ~/.bashrc`

`echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/X' >> ~/.profile`

`sudo echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/X' >> /etc/environment`

I also added the path variable to Intellij IDEA: click File -> Settings -> Path Variables and then add the variable in question (name of the program: X).

As @Jari-Jokinen mentioned above, for the IDE to use program 'X' from /path/to/X you need to restart your computer. Both Intellij IDEA and Android Studio are similar and developed by Jetbrains, so I hope this can be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

For me.

I'm using a Mac Pro 2019 with Intel Processor.

when I executed `yarn Android` I got that same error the author said.

The only thing that really works.

Looks like that, in my case, some Android Studio config was wrong.

- Uninstall Android Studio
- Delete all Android variables from bash or zrsh
- Install the latest Android studio again
- Follow the Official Guide to instal React Native to Android: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of solutions about this issue and most are talking about updating the gradle plugin. I have tested a lot of solutions and running the latest Android Studio version (Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1).

The main issue is still that AndroidStudio, with gradle version lower than 6.9.x, can not lookup properly the PATH environment, which is set by /bin/printenv tool from Android Studio application package itself. If you see in the Android Studio logfile that it can not execute the printenv command, please update to latest Android Studio version.

In 'Project Structure' select 'Gradle Version' 6.9 or higher and you can build your project properly.

[image: In 'Project Structure' select 'Gradle Version' 6.9 or higher]

Answer (score 0):

You should update Android Studio to latest version. It does work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade your Android studio to 2021.3.1.
Its working for us.

Answer (score 0):

1. close android studio
2. end any android task from the task manager
3. use terminal to build the app using

```
cd android && ./gradlew build
```

4. launch android studio
5. you should be able to run your app on a simulator

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing issue on Mac(Monterey 12.6.1).I don't know what was the exact reason but I've just upgraded my Android studio artic fox to Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1. And surprisingly my issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing helped me, just when I changed Gradle JDk it started working

[image]

Comment: In my case running one project with  "react-native": "0.61.2", worked after install  azul-11 - Azul Zulu 11.0.20, just using the gui to install.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using nvm, this can work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69066155/10047450

But you need to run `nvm use [version]` (or just `nvm use` if you have an .nvmrc configured) in the terminal before launching android studio.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a M1 Mac and are using Android Studio:

- Download Android Studio 2021.1.1 (or later).
- Install Zulu OpenJDK (https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-8-lts&os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk).
- Add `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home` to your `.zshrc`.
- On Android Studio, change the gradle settings to use JAVA_HOME to find the jdk.

Comment: This is good advice for M1, I found that same JDK as one of the few native options for JDK. But I guess it's not directly relevant to this question.