# We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

i'm  trying to use react native with android studio

i've tried import my react native project to android studio

but this error occure

```
    This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.
```

like this image

[image]

so how can i fix this error?? i've seen the Link but i don't understand.. it is not clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project doesn't know that you have a `build.gradle` file.

To solve this problem, you will need to do the following:

1. Add your settings.gradle file if you don't have one. In the file add: `include ':'`
2. Re-import everything in android studio by completing the following steps:

- Exit out of your project/back it up
- Delete the .idea    folder in the root directory of the project + delete all the .iml    files in your project
- Import your project in Android Studio, and when the dialog asks you to choose a file, select the build.gradle file

Comment: If I remove the .idea file, the android option disappears from the project category in Android Studio.

Comment: Hi, before you delete the .idea file, first back it up. Then follow the same process and finally choose to import the `build.gradle` file when you re-enter android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I went to my project folder in Terminal and ran

`open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app`

and it allowed it to access node and download the Gradle files.

Found the answer from this post: [React Native on Android: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922174/react-native-on-android-cannot-run-program-node-error-2-no-such-file-or-dir)