# Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: logger for class: org.gradle.initialization.DefaultProjectDescriptor

Tags: android-studio, gradle

running Pop OS/ Ubuntu, first time install of android studio and when I open my project gradle fails with

`Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: logger for class: org.gradle.initialization.DefaultProjectDescriptor`

```
other things I noticed unable to resolve `android` class

 // ♥ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-06-14 14:47:26 UTC


Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          16.0.1 (Homebrew 16.0.1+0)
OS:           Linux 5.11.0-7614-generic amd64
```

any help pointing in a debug direction greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to attribute this error to using an incompatible node version, when I switched from 14.15.0 to 14.5.0 the issue was resolved

Comment: I am facing the same problem. However, changing the node version does not seem to fix it for me. Are you sure the node version was the culprit of the problem or did you change something else as well?

Comment: I tried different version of node with `nvm` it didn't work either.

Comment: yes, 100% sure the node change worked for me, always happens when I change node version on my machine

Comment: upgrading the node version als worked for me ->
brew update
brew upgrade node

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue. But fix it for M1 arch.

1. Terminal -> `open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app`
2. Change your grandle version to 6.7.1 (File -> Project structure -> Gradle version)
3. Change your gradle JDK to open JDK 1.8 (Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK)

If you don't have JDK 1.8 please install

- `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8`

It's work for me.

Comment: The real fix is https://stackoverflow.com/a/70891538/9878385

Run `chmod +x /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv`

Answer (score 0):

I was using `Android Studio BumbleBee` on `OS 11.0`

Upon updating the OS to 12.0, I started getting this error.

Then updated the `Android Studio to Chipmunk` and its resolved.