# Android Studio: Cannot run program "node"

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I have project in React Native, and I'm not being able to build on the Android Studio due the following error.

Here's the detailed log with additional info:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node" (in directory "/Users/fabioernanni/git/fintech-ewallet-mobile/android"): error=2, No such file or directory

java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Cause: error=2, No such file or directory
```

I have tried to reinstall Node, Android Studio, to link the tscript library so the Android Studio would recognize the "node" but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Just as an aside, for some reason `node` was uninstalled or not available on my system. I may have upgraded things through `brew upgrade` and this is why `node` was no longer installed. It just so happened Android Studio was the first place I ran into this and so I just assumed it was Android Studio causing a ruckus when in fact it was my own fault. Might be helpful to others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native on Android: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922174/react-native-on-android-cannot-run-program-node-error-2-no-such-file-or-dir)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have a similar problem with Android Studio (bumble bee) version with node on My Mac M1 Chip  so to solve this open your Android Studio from terminal .
To Open Android Studio from terminal on Mac m1 just open your Terminal and paste the following command

```
open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

this will open your android studio and then you can open your project and can run build from android studio
**Note** : be sure that Android studio is not running state if its running just Quite it and then launch from Terminal

Comment: May I know what will happen when we opened studio from Terminal?

Comment: Im having this issue on Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1, and this solution doesn't worked for me.

Comment: @IgorRibeiro let me verify for Dolphin patch 1

Comment: @OuneebUrRehman, I fixed it by downgrading the java version, so the project was compiled earlier. I was using java 18 and downgraded to Java 11.

I don't know why, but it worked, even in this version of Android Studio.

Comment: It works for me. Can you tell me the reason why it works with command?

Comment: @ShoebMirza
It's because android studio couldn't find node and should run through terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Do these steps to solve it:-

STEP 1: First quit the android studio, if it is in a running state.

```
command + Q
```

STEP 2: Enable the permission for android studio printenv.

```
sudo chmod +x /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv
```

STEP 3: Open android studio from terminal app.

```
open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

Comment: Not working on Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639, 
macOS 13.3.1, M2 Pro

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of Gradle (specified in `gradle-wrapper.properties`) and the Android Gradle Plugin (in (`build.gradle`) that you are using.

Some versions can have known issues with specific versions of Android Studio.

This page provides more information: https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin