# Unable to start my react native expo bare workflow application on android

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, cmake, expo

I try to start my react native application initialize with expo bare workflow on android but it shows me this error

npx expo run:android
› Building app...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :expo

Using expo modules

- expo-application (5.1.1)
- expo-constants (14.2.1)
- expo-file-system (15.2.2)
- expo-font (11.1.1)
- expo-keep-awake (12.0.1)
- expo-modules-core (1.2.3)
- expo-splash-screen (0.18.1)

The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build.
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':expo', ':expo-modules-core'

> Task :expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig
> Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:

- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:compileDebugAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:compileDebugShaders' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:extractDeepLinksDebug' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:generateDebugResValues' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:mergeDebugResources' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:mergeDebugShaders' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:processDebugMainManifest' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:processDebugManifest' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:processDebugManifestForPackage' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android'. Reason: Task ':expo-constants:createDebugExpoConfig' uses this output of task ':app:processDebugResources' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[armeabi-v7a]
> C/C++: ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries

> Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[armeabi-v7a] FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[armeabi-v7a]'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android.cxx\Debug\6v603819\armeabi-v7a'
> [0/1] Re-running CMake...
> -- Configuring done
> -- Generating done
> -- Build files have been written to: D:/naDan/Ordinateur/Cours_programming/Javascript/React_Native/3Autres/UEAVote/ueavote/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/.cxx/Debug/6v603819/armeabi-v7a

C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
@echo off
"C:\Users\naDan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\ninja.exe" ^
-C ^
"D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\.cxx\Debug\6v603819\armeabi-v7a" ^
expo-modules-core
from D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android
ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.

BUILD FAILED in 3m 9s
265 actionable tasks: 44 executed, 103 from cache, 118 up-to-date
Error: D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
at ChildProcess.completionListener (D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:52:23)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
at cp.emit (D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
...
at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:17:21)
at spawnGradleAsync (D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:72:46)
at Object.assembleAsync (D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:52:18)
at runAndroidAsync (D:\naDan\Ordinateur\Cours_programming\Javascript\React_Native\3Autres\UEAVote\ueavote\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:31:24)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Answer (score 0):

The highest rated answer to this question [React Native on Android: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922174/react-native-on-android-cannot-run-program-node-error-2-no-such-file-or-dir) solved the issue for me. It also includes explanations as to why.