# React Native Build Fails in Android Studio: Node.js Version Not Detected Correctly

Tags: node.js, react-native, android-studio, nvm

### Problem

I'm working on a React Native project and recently encountered an issue with building my app in Android Studio. After updating to the newest RN version, I switched to using *nvm* instead of *nodejs* to be more flexible with older apps. But somehow I get this error:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node" (in directory "/path/to/my/project"): error=2, No such file or directory

I have installed Node.js v20.11.0 using *nvm*. Running `node -v` in the terminal correctly shows v20.11.0.

#### Environment

- **Operating System:** Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
- **React Native Version:** 0.73.2
- **Android Studio Version:** Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1

This issue persists even after setting the PATH environment variable to include the Node.js binary path in my `.bashrc` file.

#### Steps Taken

1. I have tried reinstalling Node.js using `nvm` and setting it as the default version.
2. I have added the Node.js binary path to my PATH variable in `.bashrc`.
3. I checked the Node.js version in the terminal within Android Studio, and it shows the correct version.
4. I have tried modifying Android Studio's VM options to include the correct PATH.

Despite these efforts, the build process in Android Studio still fails to recognize the correct Node.js version.

### Question

How can I configure Android Studio to recognize the Node.js version installed via `nvm`? Are there any specific settings or configurations in Android Studio that I need to adjust to ensure it uses the correct Node.js version during the build process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Ok, as proposed in this [threat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922174/react-native-on-android-cannot-run-program-node-error-2-no-such-file-or-dir), creating a symbolic link to the used *nvm* version fixes thee problem. The issue is that when using *nvm*, *Android Studio* does not where to find the node executable.

`sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/local/bin/node`